# IllegalArgumentException: setTaskFromReuseOrCreateNewTask

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the next crash when I try to launch an Activity:

```
2019-10-24 15:12:29.887 4245-4296/fr.zapotec.eliodroid.tv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
Process: fr.zapotec.eliodroid.tv, PID: 4245
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setTaskFromReuseOrCreateNewTask: task=TaskRecord{6e69142 #1643 A=fr.zapotec.eliodroid.tv U=0 StackId=1 sz=3} is in a different stack (1) than the parent of r=ActivityRecord{8062424 u0 fr.zapotec.eliodroid.tv/fr.zapotec.eliodroid.SplashActivity t1644} (0)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1955)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1897)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivities(IActivityManager.java:6812)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivitiesAsUser(Instrumentation.java:1677)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivities(Instrumentation.java:1632)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivities(ContextImpl.java:910)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivities(ContextImpl.java:884)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivities(ContextWrapper.java:399)
    at fr.zapotec.eliodroid.utils.LaunchActivityUtils.launchTVLastProgram(LaunchActivityUtils.java:22)
    at fr.zapotec.eliodroid.standby.StandbyManager.launchAction(StandbyManager.java:253)
    at fr.zapotec.eliodroid.standby.StandbyManager.onEventReceived(StandbyManager.java:141)
    at fr.zapotec.eliodroid.handset.HandsetEventDispatcherImpl.handleKeyPress(HandsetEventDispatcherImpl.java:229)
    at fr.zapotec.eliodroid.handset.HandsetEventDispatcherImpl.handleKeyPress(HandsetEventDispatcherImpl.java:204)
    at fr.zapotec.eliodroid.handset.HandsetEventDispatcherImpl.onMessageReceived(HandsetEventDispatcherImpl.java:165)
    at fr.zapotec.handsetbluetooth.HandsetManagerImpl.dispatchMessage(HandsetManagerImpl.java:49)
    at fr.zapotec.handsetbluetooth.MessageManager.onNewMessageReceived(MessageManager.java:119)
    at fr.zapotec.handsetbluetooth.HandsetThread.listenAndWrite(HandsetThread.java:126)
    at fr.zapotec.handsetbluetooth.HandsetThread.run(HandsetThread.java:56)
```

This is the Manifest file:

```
        <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:name=".StandbyActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".main.SimpleMainActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".main.InstallActivity"/>
```

I need the Activity 'SimpleMainActivity' to be one only instance (that's why the 'singleTask')
This Activity can be launched due to Bluetooth events (triggered by a bluetooth device) or due to a given timing in a very specific situation.

The method which launches the Activity is:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

I have the crash when trying to launch the Activity from the 2 different sources almost at the same time.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem without removing the 'singleTask' from my Activity?

For information, my application is the "Default launcher", so "SplashActivity" maybe be launched if system needs to show the launcher. The SplashActivity only shows a splash screen and launches the first activity (SimpleMainActivity.class)

Comment: Normally using an Activity to show a splash screen is not the correct approach. See https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Answer (score 0):

What will likely work is to use a `launchMode` of `singleTop` instead and set the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) do recommend this for activities launched by notifications.

Comment: It is not an Activity launched by a notification. it is launched by an event (bluetooth event or a given timeout). I absolutely need my Activity to be "singleTask" because of the Specifications of my system.

Comment: My point is that what you are doing is a lot like a notification and `singleTop` should give you the same behavior you are looking for if you use those flags. Can you be more specific about what would require `singleTask` specifically?

Comment: I need my Activity to be singleton whatever happens. (singleTop doesn't guarantee my Activity to be singleton). I am developping a Launcher kind app for an AndroidTV.

Comment: If you use the clear top and new task flags then it will effectively guarantee it is a singleton. Just give it a try

Comment: Not the solution I need. The given Activity can also be launched by the System due to NFC Events declared in my Manifest. I repeat, my Activity needs to be "singleTask". Thanks

Comment: Can you say why it isn't the solution you need? Instead of assuming you know what the solution is, what is the actual behavior that makes this not work? I have used this to ensure singleton instances of Activities to great effect

Comment: I explained you. I need my Activity to be singleTask. Have you ever ensure with that behaviour that NFC events triggered by Manifest declaration are still managining singleton Instances? If that the case, tell Android team the "singleTask" launchMode is useless. I need I solution which does not change the launchMode of my Activity. I was specific when I said "Anyone knows how to solve this problem without removing the 'singleTask' from my Activity?"

Comment: Since the NFC case is weird you may need to use `taskAffinity` and `allowTaskReparenting` OR catch the NFC intent using a Broadcast Receiver or other Activity and then send your own Intent to your singleton activity